# My PowerBI dashboard is connected to a cube. How to get the folder name from the file path in another column in the cube in ssas

Tags: powerbi, power-bi-report-server

How can I add a new column in my cube that is the foldername from the filepath? Do I add the cube in ssas or alter table?

I have the script for the folder name as :

Select  REVERSE(ItemPath),
IIF(ItemPath <> 'Unknown',
REVERSE(LEFT(Reverse(ItemPath),
CHARINDEX('/',
REVERSE(ItemPath)  ) -1 ) ),
ItemPath   )
AS NewItemPath
FROM [dbo].[Execution3]

My script works but I need help to altimately get the column to appear in my PowerBI dashboard.